# How to toggle material design icons in Vue JS with a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, switch-statement, icons, bootstrap-vue

I am toggling the text inside a button, but I want to toggle icons instead.
this is the code I have.

```
<b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails" class="mr-2">
  {{ row.detailsShowing ? '-' : '+'}} Details
</b-button>
```

I want to use the icons as the trigger for the toggle.
Click on the chevron down to expand and the chevron up to collapse.

```
<i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down"></i>
<i class="mdi mdi-chevron-up"></i>
```

How do I change that? Everything I am trying is breaking.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails" class="mr-2">
  <b-icon :icon="row.detailsShowing ? chevron-up : chevron-down"></b-icon> 
  Details
</b-button>
```

Comment: Thanks Dipen Shah. This works great. I appreciate the prompt help.

Comment: Works great! IMPORTANT NOTE: In my case, icon names needed to be inside single quotation marks (like this: 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down' )...